# RPM installation error: failed dependencies

Tags: linux, rpm, libraries

I'm trying to install an application on a GNU/Linux OS with RPM, however it keeps saying me that it's dependencies are failed:

```
rpm -i sap-1.7.54-0.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libncurses.so.5 is needed by sap-1.7.54-0.i686
```

That's rude as I have that `libncurses.so.5`:

```
bash-3.2# ls -lZ /usr/lib/libncurses*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     19 Nov  3 10:15 /usr/lib/libncurses++.so.6 -> libncurses++.so.6.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _  71696 Oct 23 22:27 /usr/lib/libncurses++.so.6.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     20 Nov  3 10:15 /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.6 -> libncurses++w.so.6.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _  71696 Oct 23 22:27 /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.6.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     17 Mar 17 21:14 /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _ 158528 Mar 17 21:12 /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     17 Nov  3 10:15 /usr/lib/libncurses.so.6 -> libncurses.so.6.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _ 169780 Oct 23 22:27 /usr/lib/libncurses.so.6.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     18 Mar 17 21:14 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _ 225240 Mar 17 21:12 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root _     18 Nov  3 10:15 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6 -> libncursesw.so.6.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root _ 247700 Oct 23 22:27 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.1
```

Also`ldconfig` runs without any problems. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

`rpm` only knows about files that are installed by `rpm` packages. When you run:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
```

(translation: to which package does this file belong), `rpm` will probably tell you it doesn't belong to any package.

So you have two ways to go from here:

- make sure /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 gets installed by an `rpm` package to solve your dependency problem.
- force `rpm` to ignore the dependencies (`rpm -i --nodeps sap-1.7.54-0.i686.rpm`). I do not recommend this, because this breaks all dependencies, you will never get your system clean again... only do this as a last resort.